# Maven. how to evaluate expression within pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have the maven enforcer plugin and git-id plugin. I need the enforcer plugin to work only if it is on master branch. From git-it plugin i can get the branch name and enforcer plugin has a parameter "fail". Is it possible to do something like `<fail>${branch == 'master'}</fail>` this? Is there a plugin to evaluate expressions within pom.xml or do i have to use command line arguments to pass in the value?

Or maybe is there a better way to fail a build on master branch if there are snapshot dependencies?

Comment: First question: Why should enforcer only run on master and not on a branch? Apart from that I suppose you are running on a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes jenkins. on feature branches we dont care if its snapshot or not. but for releaseso n master they all must not be snapshots.

Comment: As I wrote using a enforcer rule which can skippped on the branch very easy to handle with Jenkins call maven like: `mvn -Denforcer.skip` on the branch and on the master simply do not do that.